# How to split an array of objects into subarrays depending on the field value in Rails and Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I want to get several arrays of objects aggregated by months (and years) in a their property value.

I have class Request like this:

```
class Request  
  include Mongoid::Document  
  include MongoidDocument::Updated  

  field :name, type: String  
  field :start_date, type: DateTime  
#...
end
```

And I want the resulting  array of multiple hashes with

```
{month: m_value, year: y_value, request: requests_with_m_value_as_month_and_y_value_as_year_in_start_date_field}
```

as element of array

Can  someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to get the data in the right shape back from MongoDB:

```
db.requests.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { 
          $year: "$start_date"
        },

        month: { 
          $month: "$start_date"
        }
      },

      requests: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      year: "$_id.year",
      month: "$_id.month",
      requests: "$requests"
    }
  }
])
```

Obviously, this is using just the REPL and you will have to translate it to the DSL provided by Mongoid. Based on what I could find it should be possible to just get the underlying collection and call `aggregate` on it:

```
Request.collection.aggregate([...])
```

Now you just need to take the query and convert it into something that Mongoid will accept. I think you just need to add a bunch of quotes around the object keys but I don't the environment set up to try that myself.